# Javascript chart library where you can attach extra data to each point

Tags: javascript, charts, interactive

I would like to plot price data and include a size attribute to each point so each data point would be (time, price, size=100) for instance.  The canvas should plot the price data as a line but when hovering the mouse over the plot, I would like to be able to see the size at that point.  I've accomplished this using jfreecharts in Java but I'm looking for something in the javascript space like d3.js or similar that might be able to achieve this.  Any recommendations on charting libraries to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d3 is great, and probably the most flexible out there, but can be complicated, depending on your level of javascript. I think the most popular and easy to use libraries are:
[Chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/),
[Google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) and
[ECharts](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/index.html)

If you're a beginner, checkout something like [Anychart playground](https://playground.anychart.com/new?template=line_chart)